# Почему Pyrogram Bot отмечает пользователей в чате без уведомления?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Написал функцию /all, которая отмечает всех людей в чате.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

1. Когда отправляю команду /all в тестовый чат (10 человек), всем приходит уведомление об отметке
2. Когда отправляю команду /all в чат (200+ человек), приходит, дай бог, одному человеку уведомление

Но при этом пользователи отмечены под каждым эмодзи.

Что я делаю не так? Может существует какой-то лимит на количество отметок от бота?

````
@Client.on_message(filters.command('all'))
async def all_command(client: Client, message: Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user = message.from_user.id
    try:
        if str(user) in admins:  # Проверка на администратора
            text = []
            async for member in client.get_chat_members(chat_id):
                if member.user.is_bot: # Проверка на участника-бота
                    pass
                else:
                    text.append(f'[{random_emoji()[0]}](tg://user?id={member.user.id})')

            chunk = 75 # Разделить по 75 человек на 1 сообщение
            groups = [text[i:i + chunk] for i in range(0, len(text), chunk)]
            i = 0
            for group in groups:
                i += 1
                if i == 1:
                    mentions = 'Общий сбор!\n\n' + ''.join(group)
                    await client.delete_messages(chat_id, message.id)
                    await client.send_message(chat_id, mentions, parse_mode=enums.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
                else:
                    await client.send_message(chat_id, ''.join(group), parse_mode=enums.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.25) ```
````